# python logger level and handler level priority

Tags: python-3.x, logging, handler

If I understand python docs correctly. Python allow you set logger level with `logger.setLevel` and handler level with `handler.setLevel`. The final level will be the intersection of two level which is narrower one.

My question is is there any method to allow me ignore logger level and use my handler level domain?

```
import logging
logger.setLevel('Error')
logger.addHandler(handler)
handler.setLevel('INFO')
```

The final level for handler will be `Error` but I want it to be `INFO`